# Почему instagram использует такие странные названия классов?

Tags: css, instagram

Хотелось бы узнать почему на сайте Instagram используются такие названия для классов CSS? Сам веб-разработчик, и редко наблюдаю такие странные названия классов. Возможно ли что это какая-то библиотека?

Спасибо, просьба не минусовать т.к сугубо профессиональный интерес.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: С большей долей вероятности это сделано во избежание скрейпинга страниц. Делается это при сборке проекта, каким именно сборщиком подсказать не могу, какие-то оптимайзеры и дополнительные модули могут идти в gulp/webpack.

Comment: Названия даются автоматически во всяких angular и прочих подобных либах, потому что там работают с компонентами, а не классами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причин может быть несколько.

- Усложнение работы программистам, пишущих роботов для сбора контента.
- Минимизация веса страницы, иногда даже в разы.

Как такое делают - достаточно подробно описано [там](https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda), правда только для React.